# Robust Spline Fitting to Points on 2D Trajectory

Tags: scipy, interpolation

I have some data which plots a trajectory in 2D. I would like to fit an interpolating curve to this data and I thought a cubic spline between each set of three consecutive points would work well. I am a bit confused by the interpolate functions in `scipy` however. Here's what I currently have:

```
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [398.01543948 400.99034244 402.36995272 401.05813953 398.65277778
 395.97260274 393.08474576 390.325      387.42105263 384.17073171
 380.42028986 377.20754717 373.80769231 370.04545455 366.796875
 363.33823529 359.63636364 356.22033898 352.95555556 349.41176471
 345.87878788 341.89189189 337.91666667 334.84482759 331.60273973
 328.         296.51515152 293.91176471 290.31111111 287.16666667
 283.97222222 281.56       278.79591837 276.32631579 273.65195849
 271.53191489 270.25503356 279.75497404 276.09359445 270.42035064
 298.7761194  298.74285714]
ys = [172.76204179 176.63910967 179.49095377 180.34710744 180.82075472
 181.04255319 181.07368421 181.06382979 181.1875     181.21875
 181.15909091 181.06410256 181.         181.01923077 180.84615385
 180.8125     180.69135802 180.69565217 180.68       180.68571429
 180.69117647 180.62264151 180.87323944 180.71666667 180.63333333
 180.64788732 181.4137931  180.94871795 181.31372549 181.25
 181.02       180.53030303 180.63541667 180.73529412 180.72631579
 180.00884956 179.03915758 172.17751105 171.69548635 173.73376084
 156.93617021 156.52671756]

tck, u = interpolate.splprep([xs, ys])
x_i, y_i = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 100), tck)

plt.plot(x_i, y_i)
plt.scatter(xs, ys, c='r')
plt.show()
```

The result is this:[image]

Now I understand that everything is working as advertised, but I was wondering if there is some way to set a limit on the derivatives or the smoothness of the resulting spline, to get rid of artefacts like that ugly spike.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your last five points (marked green below) are in "incorrect" order and the spline needs to go threw them in that order. If you order your last five points by `ys` value and adjust your `s` value a little bit you get the following.

```
idx = np.arange(ys.shape[0])
idx[-5:] = np.flip(idx[-5:][np.argsort(ys[-5:])])

tck, u = interpolate.splprep([xs[idx], ys[idx]], s=40)
x_i, y_i = interpolate.splev(np.linspace(0, 1, 100), tck)

plt.plot(x_i, y_i)
plt.scatter(xs, ys, c='r')
plt.scatter(xs[-5:], ys[-5:], c='g')
```

[image]

### So you're saying I have to remove/order outliers by hand?

No. The problem is that the spline interpolation respects order. So it's not the line closest to your points but it first close to your first point 2nd to your 2nd point etc.. One solution would be to order your points like I did above. Alternatively to doing that by hand you can use a heuristic. Since we are starting with a very reasonable ordering a local optimization should give us a much better probably optimal order. By local optimization I mean that I just swap two points if that shortens the overall distance until there are no two points that do that anymore. In your case this gives exactly the ordering I proposed above

```
def combinations(arr):
    n = arr.shape[0]
    upper = np.tri(n,n,-1,dtype='bool').T
    a,b = np.meshgrid(arr,arr)
    return b[upper].reshape(-1), a[upper].reshape(-1)

idx = np.arange(xs.shape[0])
grid = np.meshgrid(idx,idx)
distances = ((xs[grid[0]]-xs[grid[1]])**2+(ys[grid[0]]-ys[grid[1]])**2)**(1/2)

idx = np.arange(distances.shape[0])

def local_opt(idx, dist):
    current_distance = calc_dist(idx, dist)
    for i,j in itertools.combinations(idx, 2):
            idx[i], idx[j] = idx[j], idx[i]
            if calc_dist(idx, dist) < current_distance:
                return local_opt(idx,dist)
            idx[i], idx[j] = idx[j], idx[i]
    return idx

def calc_dist(idx, dist):
    return dist[idx[:-1],np.roll(idx,-1)[:-1]].sum()

idx = local_opt(idx,distances)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try monotone interpolants, e.g. Pchip or Akima1DInterpolator. The first shot could be to cook up the parametrization of the curve (e.g. the line length via the cartesian distance  --- but you man need to play with various parametrizations since they do produce different curves) and use a monotone interpolant. They support multidim `y` values, so you can ibterpolate both your coirdinates vs arc length.

Alternatively, you can play with the `s` parameter of `splrep` which controls the amount of smoothing.